# I can't import markup in my django project

Tags: django, markup

The current version of my using django is 1.6.3

i write a code

```
{% load markup %}
```

in my blog_list.html

and i got error says

```
'markup' is not a valid tag library: Template library markup not found, tried django.templatetags.markup,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.markup,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.markup`
```

So i check the docs , and i found the way, then i add 'django.contrib.markup' to INSTALL_APPS settings. when i run server i got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named markup
```

So i searched markup with macports,and i installed the py27-markupsafe. And i can't import it either. What am i suppose to do ?

Comment: after checking the docs, markup does not appear to be a valid template tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: you'll have to load custom tags with `{% load my_custom_tag_name %}`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 4):

If you have a look at the [Django Depreciation Timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/internals/deprecation/#id2) you'll notice the following:

```
django.contrib.markup will be removed following an accelerated deprecation.
```

which means that markup is not automatically included with Django as of 1.6. You can read more about it [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18054).

As a replacement, I have had success with [`django-markdown-deux`](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux) which once installed provides a template tag:

```
{% load markdown_deux_tags %}
{{ myvar|markdown }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using old Django (before this was depricated), add the following to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py:

'django.contrib.markup'

That should do the trick.